# Unable to get policy object when running pipeline from Startup class Config method in Commerce Engine in Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1

Tags: pipelines, sitecore-commerce

I created a pipeline with only one block, on the block implementation I get a `Policy` object, something like this:

```
var testPolicy = context.GetPolicy<TestPolicy>();
Condition.Requires(testPolicy).IsNotNull("testPolicy is missing");
Condition.Requires(testPolicy.Test).IsNotNullOrEmpty("The testPolicy.Test can not be null or empty");
```

I need to run this pipeline only once, since it will spin one thread that will be doing some work while the app is running, so that's why I'm trying to run it from the Startup class Configure method like this:

```
Task.Run(() => testPipeline.Run(string.Empty, NodeContext.GetPipelineContextOptions()));
```

But in this case the `testPolicy.Test` won't be loaded properly, so the assertion will fail.

If I setup this pipeline to run as part of any existing one for example any of the carts pipeline it will properly load the `testPolicy.Test` so it is not an issue with the policy setting on the environments json files or anything like that. My guess is that at that point (running from Startup class Configure method) the `CommerceContext` or something else is not completely loaded/setup...?

Anyway, I guess the question really is, where can I start this pipeline so that it gets executed only once (as soon as the app starts) without any issue loading policy objects?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your pipeline in another way from Configure method in `Startup.cs`:

```
testPipeline.Run(this.NodeContext, this.NodeContext.GetPipelineContextOptions()).Wait();
```

This is OOTB example how to run pipeline. Also, try to add your code in the end of `Configure` method.

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the things I already tried and didn't work, my line is the last one in `Configure` method, also tried this one `testPipeline.Run(string.Empty, NodeContext.GetPipelineContextOptions());`

Comment: try to call .Wait() for run your pipeline synchronously

Comment: That's what I said, I tried with your example with the .Wait() also without it and it doesn't work

Comment: First of all you should be sure that you added your pipeline configuration to right Environment Configuration. After that you need to run Bootstrap() and check again your pipeline run

Comment: My pipeline is configured in code, in my plugin ConfigureSitecore class, as I mentioned in the description of the problem, my pipeline runs fine if it is executed from any other place, for example, if I insert my pipeline in the add cart line pipeline or any other existing one it runs perfectly but of course I don't want that, I want to run it only one time as soon as the engine starts (the purpose of the pipeline is to start a new thread that will be listening for messages on a queue, so that is why I need it to run only one time right after the engine starts).

Comment: ...also the first line in the only block that the pipeline has is a log entry `_logger.LogInformation($"{Name}: Started!");` which is logged fine, the line that fails is the one asserting the policy property, all the policy properties are null or empty.

Comment: Try to configure your pipeline in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs file

Answer (score 1):

`IStartEnvironmentPipeline` is run every time the environment process starts, so if you'd like to run some code on startup it's best to define a block for that pipeline.

Also, it's a good idea to guard for `HasPipeline<TestPolicy>` and return early if it doesn't exist. This will let you continue to use the engine engine code and start your custom job in environments that define the policy, but not ones that don't.